# Align and sub-indexes.

Tags: align

Consider

```
\begin{align}
u_j &= x\\
v &= x
\end{align}
```

Compiling this the $=$'s are going to be aligned, but the $v$ gets aligned to the end of the $u_j$, which is a bit beyond the end of the $u$ because this has a sub-index.

**Question:** Is there a robust way of correcting this?

Comment: `v\phantom{_j} &= x`.  A related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111722/microtypography-on-equations/

Comment: I intended to mean by robust something that is not a tweak like this. But seen this solution made me think that there is no way for latex to know the extra space is coming from a sub-index or not. I should have though the question better.

Comment: Oh, the link is interesting.

Comment: The `tabstackengine` package can do it without a tweak: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\TABbinaryLeft
\tabbedCenterstack[l]{
u_j &= x\\
v &= x
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}`.  However, it can't (yet) number each equation separately, as does `align`.  Also, there are some configuration commands as overhead, so unless you were to use it often, the tweak is easier for your example.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the `hphantom{}` approach (which I would consider better in this specific case), then you can use the `alignat` environment which provides pairs of `r`/`l` alignment points:

[image]

### Notes:

- The first `&` makes the content following `l`eft aligned. Then you need to skip past the subsequent `r`ight aligned column (hence the `&&`) to get the `x` to be `l`eft aligned.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
    &u_j &&= x\\
    &v   &&= x
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```