# Compress equation horizontally

Tags: equations

Is there a command that compresses equation horizontally, so that everything is closer together in the horizontal direction?

This is not for a real document but rather just for viewing and playing around.

Comment: Not clear what do you want. Consider adding an MWE, at least specify `\documentclass`.

Comment: \small ?........

Comment: Do you want, e.g., no (or at least less than normal amounts of) space around `+`, `-`, and `=` symbols?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Wouldn't `\small` reduce things vertically as well as horizontally?

Comment: You could use the graphics package to rescale it.

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111722/15925

Comment: @Mico which translates as "make it look reasonable:-)" yes, it would.

Answer (score 23):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\z{
\par
\noindent X\dotfill X\[
a+b^{x+y} + \sum_{i=0}^n(x+y)^i + \sqrt{x+y+z} =  2 < a\frac{1+2}{3}b
\]}

\begin{document}

\z

{\small\z}

\medmuskip=0mu
\thinmuskip=0mu
\thickmuskip=0mu

\z

\medmuskip=-2mu
\thinmuskip=-2mu
\thickmuskip=-2mu
\nulldelimiterspace=-1pt
\scriptspace=0pt
\z
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's strange that some things (eg things in double-fractions "\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{3}") don't get affected that much by changing the parameters \medmuskip etc. Any reason for this or how one could fix that?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if one have an expression of the form `\frac{A\times\frac{B}{C}}{D\times\frac{E}{F}}` and then one plays around with the parameters `\medmuskip` etc and the others...`A` and `D`  changes but `B, C, E and F` do not since they occur as "`double-fractions`". Any idea why and how to fix that?

Comment: Doesn't `\nulldelimiterspace` get around fractions, tho? Also you could squeeze a wee bit more with `\scriptspace`.

Comment: @LoveLearning the additional medmuskip spacing around infix operators isn't added to scripts (or nested fractions which are set in same style)  so (unless you make it negative) there is no more space to be gained there, and don't make them negative in a real document:=)

Comment: Is it possible to just divide all lengths by 2 for instance? Something like \medmuskip=\medmuskip/2?

Comment: @pluton `\divide\medmuskip by 2`  or `\medmuskip=\muexpr\medmuskip/2\relax`

Answer (score 1):

Probably your equation is a little bit too long. Then you can manually scale it using `\scalebox`. Certainly, if the scale factor is far from 1, it must look ugly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
1<12345667890123456789012345678901234566789012345678901234567890
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\scalebox{0.95}[1]{$1<12345667890123456789012345678901234566789012345678901234567890$}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \scalebox seems to have some conflict with "aligned" inside "equation".