# control horizontal spacing of each equation

Tags: spacing

Is there any way to change the horizontal spacing between the characters of an equation environment and also be versatile enough so as to be able to set different spacing for different equations?

---

The recommended post does not cover my question, since it is aboout how to enter *individual spaces* between characters. My question is whether exists a method to automatically insert the desired space between *each one of the characters* of an equation. To be more specific, is there, for example, a way to transform the expression `\[a+b=c\]` to the expression `\[a\,+\,b\,=\,c\]`, without entering each one of the `\,`'s by hand between the characters of the initial expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing)

Comment: There are many ways to set horizontal spacing, see the link of the previous comment.

Comment: You might be interested in [How to change default for spacing around binary relations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55512/5764) (possible duplicate).

Comment: It answers partially my question. Now I need a way to control spacing between characters and not only around binary operators and relations. How would I transform $A,B,C$ to $A\!,\!B\!,\!C$, for example.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111722/15925 help?

Comment: @user3257624: I foresee you wanting a global solution, only to find tomorrow that you want to change it for specific things here and there. My suggestion would be to not attempt to change anything, since the consensus is that math display and spacing already does a good job.

Comment: There is also `$A{,}B{,}C{,}$` to override the `\mathpunct` nature of the comma.

Comment: You could temporarily remove override the `\mathpunct` nature of the comma, and later restore it, thus: \let\svcomma,
\catcode ` ,=\active 
\def,{{\svcomma}}
$A, B, C$
\catcode ` ,=12`  (I added extra spaces around the backticks to avoid being interpreted as markup.)

Comment: @Andrew Swann: not really, but thank's. @ Werner : I think your former suggestion is the one closest to my needs and, so far, it is sufficient for my purposes